# How do I include - and ' in this regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a this regular expression below for some input name fields. How do I include an apostrophe and a hyphen in this?

```
InputField("tFName", /^[a-zA-Z-\-\ ]+$/);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hyphen is already included (twice), you can add the apostrophe by just editing it into the character class:

```
/^[a-zA-Z-\-\ ']+$/
```

You can rewrite it to look like this, so that there's no need to escape the hyphen and it's only included once:

```
/^[a-zA-Z '-]+$/
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/**

Comment: I tried it like this: /^[a-zA-Z '-]+$/
but I am still getting an error

Comment: could try `/^([a-zA-Z]|(\-*)|(\'*))+$/`

Comment: That did not work it escaped the hyphen but not the apostrophe.

Comment: @Moja Ra not sure at what point you tried, I edited the regex so might want to take another look.

Comment: It is not allowing the apostrophe the way it is written /^([a-zA-Z]|(\-*)|(\'*))+$/

Comment: I am able to escape the hyphen but I am still not able to escape the apostrophe in this regular expression for javascript.

Comment: just another option... I'd try this myself but I dont have a way to test it on this computer at the moment. `/^([a-zA-Z]|(\-*)|['])+$/`

Comment: @Moja Ra alright, I'm sorry I wasn't able to help further. After I get home I will test some options and post back here if you don't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Moja: the regular expression I gave you works just fine - I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"abc'def ghi-jkl mno-pq'rst".match(/^[\w\s-']+$/)
```

- `\w` for any letter
- `\s` for space
- `-` for hyphen
- `'` for apostrophe

Comment: `\s` will match more than just space - `\t\r\n`, among others, are also included. Also, `\w` will match `_`.

Comment: @andy It is quite hard to get a \t\r\n in an input field but ok for the \w and _

Comment: @Mic: it's easier than you think, you'd be surprised how many people accidentally highlight an `\n` or `\r\n` when copy-pasting ;-) Although, that is what trimming is for.

Comment: @andy Sure? I thought the \n\r were removed automatically from the value attribute of an INPUT.

Comment: @Mic: of course, you are right - it is still possible to paste a \t though ;-)